# How to mask always encrypted value in the application layer?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, odbc, sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

I have an always-encrypted column using `SQL Server 2016 SP1 Standard Edition` and and the `ODBC driver` in combination with `ADO`.

Everything is working fine, but when a user has no access to the encryption keys, the encrypted value is returned. This is not very user friendly and I want to return `not access` or something instead.

The question is can I check in the application or in the SQL Server which keys the current user have access to? Then using this `true` or `false` with combination of the database connection string (has or has not `ColumnEncryption=Enabled`) I can mask the values in the applications.

Or it will be best, if there is some technique for solving this in the SQL Server and mask the value there?